# What large scale strategies would an interstellar nation use to conquer another interstellar nation?

Tags: science-fiction, warfare, space-warfare, governance

I'm working on a science fiction setting for a game. I'm trying to write a setting that focuses on man-operated war machines in sight range combat. Everything ranging from fighters to mechs to capital ships would be used and have logical reasons within the setting to steer combat towards that approach.

One of the factions are a group of colonies that had declared independence from Earth decades ago and had managed to win it. These colonies since declared themselves a new interstellar nation with a strong economy, but their military power has always been limited by their low relative population compared to other interstellar nations. Their military doctrines lean heavily into getting the most out of the individual in their military forces and maximizing the survival rates of their pilots and crews (think large war machines with small crew/pilot counts and lots of armor.)

Over the decades since, interest in reclaiming these outer colonies would change with each election cycle, sometimes sparking one of many short lived wars to reunite humanity under one rule. At best, they would manage a stalemate, at worst, they would be pushed back.

I'm trying to figure out what the strategy of the Earth military would be in trying to re-establish control over these colonies. I imagine landing troops wouldn't really work on a planetary scale as they would need pretty much need an occupation force far larger than would be sensible to maintain. Though a strategy of precise military strikes on the ground might work?

I know that taking points of interest might be a factor, as well, factories that produce war machines, shipyards and the like. Anything that might help them establish a foothold in enemy territory.

I should also mention that robotic and other autonomous combatants are specifically outlawed by treaties signed by multiple interstellar nations that I'm still working on the details of. A robot/drone army isn't an option for them.

The only real strategy I can think of is blockading planets and taking control of the system gates to force a world into submission. FTL between systems utilizes artificial wormholes generated by massive gates that are expensive to produce, so it would be easy to control travel to and from a system by shutting off gates.

Armed incursions might only be limited to things like seizing factories, military bases and shipyards to limit the colony's ability to fight back while under that blockade.

What are some other strategies that might come into play in this scenario?

Comment: This migjt be hard to answer. How much detail do you expect? Although the simplest answer would probably be "any and all strategies used in WWII with a few adaptations to account for any anomalous technologies". The type of space-faring is also important. Is this the overly simplistic "you capture orbital space and then land on the planet" or is this a more realistic "you have to simultaneously fight orbital defenses in space and on the ground to defeat a planet" that for some reason no one ever uses.

Comment: "What are some other strategies" would be broad, open-ended and be of the asking for an [infinite list](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6130/catalog-of-question-types/7376#7376) variety which is considered off-topic. If you can narrow the question to a specific area of interest, then maybe if you don't find what you need, ask another question in another area of interest, that would work fine.

Comment: What are the rules of engagement here?  Do both sides abide by the Geneva convention and 20th century Western sensibilities or is anything goes, including borderline war crimes (or actual war crimes) as was the case in pre-modern times?

Answer (score 1):

The prime advantage Earth has is that their opponents are a a league or alliance of multiple worlds whereas Earth is a singular political entity. Use that against them.

**Step 1** - *study your opponent*. Identify the economic interactions and geographical distribution of the colony worlds and determine which if any worlds are reliant on others for key inputs and if so what those inputs are.  That lets you prioritize your targets, who is closest vs who is stronger, who is weaker, who has the best military, who is the biggest threat etc. Then do the same for yourself - identify your weak points and vulnerabilities and protect or limit them as you can.

**Step 2** - *The gates are the key*. Attack those States identified as priority targets and seize control of their gates. Then be prepared to  defend them from heavy and repeated counter-attack.

***Step 3*** - *Disrupt traffic* through those gates you can't seize - **mine them & or raid them**. Place automated defenses on the approaches to various gates. Then re seed as often as possible. Engage in attacks of opportunity on convoys etc with whatever forces you can spare. You wont be able to stop the enemy from clearing or using those gates but you will cause losses, delays and most importantly economic disruption.

**Step 4** - *Divide and conquer* . Offer *extremely* generous terms to selected worlds if they rejoin a union with Earth that gives them a high degree of political and economic autonomy under a Terran lead, unified military command. (Then don't screw it up by reneging on your agreements. Stick to them -its cheaper to give concessions than be constantly putting down rebellions.) If/when other worlds start seeking similar offers - give them, if on slightly less generous terms to begin with. If/when you win - even everything up over time so that all worlds are on an even footing for the sake of unity.

With luck no ground assaults or orbital bombardments would be required. Battle would be restricted to space.

One final point. Your fooling yourself if you think your opponents won't throw out any treaties they may have signed about AI/autonomous vehicle production if they're threatened with attack or look like losing the war. They *will* start automating asap, especially if as stated they are outnumbered. It would be suicide not to - so be prepared to do the same.

(Also kind of hard to see how you could get to the level of an interstellar civilization without all the stuff banned by treaty in the first place.)

Answer (score 1):

The Earth military wants a world and wants it fast?
Well, modern civilization is only possible because of an immense and delicate web of infrastructure and none of that infrastructure is hidden or hardened.

1. Secure the space around the planet.
2. Destroy all satellites in orbit.  This disrupts navigation systems, weather forecasting, communications, etc.  Note that global transport networks depend heavily on both satellite navigation and weather forecasting.
3. Carefully drop kinetic impactors from orbit onto civilian infrastructure while minimizing casualties: water treatment plants, power plants, communications, and other infrastructure.  (It's worth noting that all electronic banking depends on a functioning communications network, so commerce and manufacturing grinds to a halt.)
4. Give an ultimatum: surrender and disarm or try to survive without water, power, communications, etc.
5. Deliver the supplies necessary to restore infrastructure after the surrender with the open threat of turning things back off if a rebellion breaks out.

Manufacturing becomes impossible without power,  communications, or supplies.  The planet's inhabitants are unable to harm the invader in orbit and will be starving.  Surrender is a foregone conclusion.

Comment: I suspect that if there are reasons for CQC combat to take place that there is no "careful" dropping of kinetic impactors

Answer (score 1):

**Economic dependence**

Machiavelli pondered the same question. He saw that overpowering your enemy lead to a lot of trouble. Besides that you're likely to destroy a lot of valuable infrastructure and buildings, you will also make the conquered hate you. Even if you do something like the Romans and let them have their own culture and such, most will have lost loved ones. The Romans also added technology and such to improve the lives, which here is likely not the case. You would need to eradicate basically the whole population to prevent it from being an economic sink and even then you'll destroy valuable infrastructure.

To get the colonies to fall in line, economic dependence is your best bet. Start heavily trading with them. They probably have things they need from you, while you need things from them. Just don't budge on the cultural aspect, requiring them more and more to conform to your cultural ways of trade. In many years, possibly taking a generation or two, the question will be raised by people with less long memories. Why aren't we one state again? Even if they don't become one state, the interdependence might already make it more or less one empire. You'll have a lot of control via economics and trade, without the utter destruction.

From many perspectives war is just inefficient and unjustified. A full scale war might be more interesting to write about, but just isn't as feasible.

**War options**

If you still want war, you should target everything that has a small amount of military might that it is easily overwhelmed. Space faring people get many resources from outside the planet, as they can be easily accessible in abundance. You don't want to live on a Jupiter planet or some asteroids, but they do have very important resources in abundance. Targeting these, as well as any transport ships to and from the main colony population centers, will allow you to control the colony itself in the long run. The economic dependence will come automatically, as you offer them resources in return for more control.